# How to delete a picture from a JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, image, jtextpane

I have a code that makes it possible for a user to insert a picture into his text document.
I do have a JtextPane where the user can write some text and insert a picture.
But if the picture is inserted already its impossible to delte it without closing the whole program.
How can user delete picture by pressing backspace?

My code right now:

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            int option = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

            if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
            image = Scalr.resize(image, 150);
            document = (StyledDocument)textPane.getDocument();
            javax.swing.text.Style style = document.addStyle("StyleName", null);
            StyleConstants.setIcon(style, new ImageIcon(image));
            document.insertString(document.getLength(), "ignored text", style);
        } 

        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }

            if (option == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION){


                fileChooser.setVisible(false);

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the method `removeStyle(String stylename)` [link to javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#removeStyle%28java.lang.String%29)

In summery, what you need to do is provide the above method with the name of the style you wish to remove from the document. So in your case that would be (based on your example)

```
textPane.removeStyle("StyleName");
```

Now, to delete it using backspace, you will need to keep track of which caret positions images where inserted(or rather, styles containing images), and what the corresponding stylenames names where. Then, on backspace, continuously check if any needs to be deleted, and if so, use `removeStyle("relevantStyleName")` to delete it